# How to get the first class of the class attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-awesome

I have this in my class:

```
fab fa-facebook mbr-iconfont hoversel nosort hoverstamp
```

I just need to get the font-awesome icon classes from multiple classes as above.

I tried:

```
jObj.class.split(" ")[0]
```

But obviously this will get:

```
fab
```

But i want:

```
fab fa-facebook
```

Also to remember the font awesome class may be different like:

```
[fa, fas, fab] fa-linedin
```

So how do I achieve this, I'm thinking regex which i will try now while the question is up.

A possible answer could be:

```
jObj.class.split(" ")[0] + jObj.class.split(" ")[1]
```

But I need something more cleaner.

Comment: `.match(/(fa[sb]?).*(fa-[^\s]+)/)`

Comment: this kind of worked, the match returned an array of 3 items Array(3) ["fab fa-facebook", "fab", "fa-facebook"], so i did this jObj.class.match(/(fa[sb]?).*(fa-[^\s]+)/)[0]

Comment: Can I ask why you feel the need to do this? Accessing CSS classes in this manner at runtime is indicative of a larger code smell.

Comment: i storing the classes in memory and pulling out the class value from memory and updating the class variable that way, im not trying to modify the dom as i just want to hold the classes in a variable

Comment: In that case use the `classlist`property of the element. Do not work with the class attribute as a string.

Comment: im not modifying the class of the element, im trying to keep a hold of the classes in memory.... the classes are coming back from a property of a json object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
  const classStr = "fab fa-facebook mbr-iconfont hoversel nosort hoverstamp";
  const fontAwasomeClasses = classStr
    .split(" ")
    .filter(word => word.startsWith("fa"));
  console.log(fontAwasomeClasses);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const el = document.querySelector('div[class*="fa-"]')

function getFAClasses(classList){
  const arr = [],
  iterator = classList.values()
  for(value of iterator){
    if(value.includes('fa')){
      arr.push(value)
    }
  }
  return arr
}

const result = getFAClasses(el.classList)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<div class='fab fa-facebook mbr-iconfont hoversel nosort hoverstamp'></div>
```